# How to plot a histogram with various variables in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a scenario where I have a dataset in which there are results of India's total ODI matches played since 2018 with each and every team. If India won 5 matches out of 6 with South Africa, then the value of 'Ind1' variable is 5 and that of SA = 1. Likewise, I have stored the variables for matches played with all other teams. Now I would like to plot the values of Ind1 and SA together and that of Ind2 and Eng together and so on.

Can anyone please help me in plotting this using histogram or any other plotting technique in python!

```
plt.hist(Ind1, Sa, bins = 20, alpha = 0.5, c = 'blue')
```

The expected result is plotting two bars together with variables of the first 2 bars being 'Ind1' and 'SA' and next two bars together with variables 'Ind2' and 'Eng' and so on. I want all the bars in one graph and also together.

But I am getting an error as follows;

TypeError: hist() got multiple values for argument 'bins'

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist), the signature of `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()` is:

> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, bins=None, range=None, density=None, weights=None, cumulative=False, bottom=None, histtype='bar', align='mid', orientation='vertical', rwidth=None, log=False, color=None, label=None, stacked=False, normed=None, *, data=None, **kwargs)

Thus you are passing two values for `bins`: `Sa` (second positional argument) and `20` (keyword argument). I'm not super familiar with pyplot, but it seems like perhaps you intended to do:

```
plt.hist((Ind1, Sa), bins = 20, alpha = 0.5, c = 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your series in some sort of a container (tuple, list, etc.) as the first parameter. You'll have to either specify colors for each series or let it use defaults.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ind1 = np.random.randn(1000)
Sa = np.random.randn(1000)

plt.hist([Ind1, Sa], bins = 20, alpha = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]